# Scala Future + sleep runs slower and slower

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, future

The following snippet is concurrent tasks.
I'm expecting that the final task would have run at the 5th seconds after first one. But it runs task interval longer and longer (> 10 seconds to complete the program).

```
import java.time._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

(1 to 50).map { i =>
  Future {Thread.sleep(100 * i)}.map { _ =>
    println(s"run ${i}th task at ${LocalDateTime.now}")
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
I just want throttle my concurrency that has same time-interval between starting . Is there alternative better way ?

UPDATE:
the following snippet do nearly what I want, but it has different semantic as above snippet (insideing Await when error occur, the above stops immediately; the latter run to end without regarding fails.)

```
  (1 to 50).map { i =>
    Thread.sleep(100)
    Future{println(s"run ${i}th task at ${LocalDateTime.now}")}
  }
```

I'm also thinking about `event loop`, but this is not provided in Scala stdlib.

Comment: Your sleep is the key here. Why don't you reduce the sleep time multiply unit say somewhere as 25?

Comment: What did you expect? The total time that your threads sleep is something like `50 * 51 / 2 * 100 = 127500` milliseconds. In particular, the total time is `O(N^2)`, where `N = 50`, so that each "sleep" becomes longer and longer. You need some kind of Scheduler that schedules jobs after time-out. Are you on Akka?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Do you want your tasks to run in a given order?

Comment: I want same sleep interval between tasks starting.

Answer (score 2):

`Future`s body is not called immediately. 
It is passed to the execution context and it schedules it depending on its configuration.
In your case `global` execution context has a fixed number of threads based on the number of CPU cores. 
If there are, say, 8 threads in the pool, the last task has to wait for ~42 tasks to complete before start.